# Anti-forgery validation fails when using Azure AD auth

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are implementing `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in our AAD authenticated application. The login is working fine but when we click a button on home page it needs to call a controller action. It is failing to call controller action with below exception. Any idea to resolve this issue?

**Error:**

> [HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "xyz@microsoft.com", but the current user is "".]

**html:**

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div id="LoginList">
                <p>
                    @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders) {
                        <md-button type="submit" class="btn facebook-theme-background" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">Login with @p.AuthenticationType</md-button>
                    }
                </p>
            </div>
        }
```

**Server Side:** It is not even entering this method. When I comment `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` then it is entering.

```
    [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
}
```

**Using below two properties for authentication:**

```
    <add key="Tenant" value="xyz.onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="Audience" value="<guid>" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reproduce this issue, however failed. It seems that the issue is relative to the code. You can refer the code sample which works well for me from [this link](https://github.com/VitorX/webapp-aad-localaccount).

If you still have the problem, you may share a run-able demo to help reproducing this issue.